# Replace multiple list elements at the same time (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given two lists (a and b), I'd like to replace three elements of list 'a' with three elements of list 'b'. Currently I am using an expression like this:

```
a[0], a[5], a[7] = b[11], b[99], b[2]
```

As I need to do such operations very frequently with lots of different arrays I am wondering if there is a more compact solution for this problem (the number of elements I need to replace is always 3 though). I was thinking about something like:

```
a[0,5,7] = b[11,99,2]
```

Which obviously does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a python list you can do something like this :

```
toReplace = [0,5,7]
targetIndices = [11, 99, 2]

for i,j in zip(toReplace, targetIndices): a[i] = b[j]
```

If you've a numpy array, it's even simpler :

```
a[toReplace] = b[targetIndices]
#i.e, a[[0,5,7]] = b[[11, 99, 2]]
```

Comment: This simplifies the code when you need to replace fair amount of elements, but not when you need to replace only a couple of them. I have specified my question more, I always need to replace three element at a given time.

Comment: @Istvanb if you've a python list, then that's all you can do, just in case you've a numpy array you can do something like you want to do, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some better solutions but this does the trick:

```
ind1 = [0,5,7] 
ind2 = [11,99,2]

for i in range(len(ind1)):
    a[ind1[i]]=b[ind2[i]]
```

Comment: This simplifies the code when you need to replace fair amount of elements, but not when you need to replace only a couple of them. I have specified my question more, I always need to replace three element at a given time.